# Installing Ceph on a shared block device rather than a dedicated block device

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I am trying to install Ceph on K8s. I have 1 worker and 1 master. I have limited drives which are all in use but pretty huge in size.

Can I install ceph on a shared block device rather than a dedicated block device?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a block device is not possible. (I'm 99% sure of this)

You can however use lvm to create multiple logical volumes based on one physical volume. Then you can share the underlying block device.